# How to make two (possibly far away) equations be numbered as subequations?

Tags: equations, numbering, subequations

I have the following Latex equations:

```
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:e1}
\begin{equation}
z = \min_x\{c^Tx + W(x), x\geq 0\}
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

some text as long as a paragraph

\begin{equation}\label{eq:eq2}
W(x) = \min_w\{k^Tw-x : w\geq0\}
\end{equation}
```

Essentially, I would like `eq:eq2` to be numbered as a part of `eq:eq1`. That is if `eq:eq1` is numbered `3a` I would like `eq:eq2` to be numbered `3b`.

I tried a bit with `\tag` but cant get it to work, and I have not found a suitable answer anywhere (probably because I really don't know to look for).

**NOTE**:
Of course I can assign the `tag` `3a` to one and `3b` to the other, but then I might disrupt the general numbering of the rest of the paper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just place your paragraph in between:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\label{eq:e}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:e1}
z = \min_x\{c^Tx + W(x), x\geq 0\}
\end{equation}
some text as long as a paragraph
some text as long as a paragraph
some text as long as a paragraph
some text as long as a paragraph
some text as long as a paragraph
some text as long as a paragraph
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:e2}
W(x) = \min_w\{k^Tw-x : w\geq0\}
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

Example \eqref{eq:e1} and \eqref{eq:e2} and \eqref{eq:e}

\end{document}
```

Note also where the `\label` commands should be issued to reference the right items: if you label the whole `subequations` environment you get the number common to all the sub-equations(e.g. (1)), if you label the individual equations you get the individual number (e.g. (1b)).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Intertext works here, also.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:e}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:e1}
z & = \min_x\{c^Tx + W(x), x\geq 0\} \\
\intertext{\lipsum[1]}
\label{eq:e2}
W(x) & = \min_w\{k^Tw-x : w\geq0\}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

Example \eqref{eq:e1} and \eqref{eq:e2} and \eqref{eq:e}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's so important to preserve alignment of equals signs between the two equations; actually, I believe it shouldn't.

Comment: True, albeit that it depends on the distance between the two equations.  Besides, it doesn't only apply to `align` but also to other multi-equation environments.